# How can I access a class variable inside a class function?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following code where I tried to replace createModal with a class called Modal. However when I tried this typescript gives me errors and says that "link does not exist in the current scope":

```
module Admin.MyAccount.Access {

    export function createModal(link: Link) {
        link.Modal.$Modal = $.modal({
            resizeOnLoad: true
        });
        link.Modal.$Modal.applyTemplateSetup()
    }

    export class Modal {
        link: Link;
        constructor (link: Link) {
            this.link = link;
        }
        create() {
            link.Modal.$Modal = $.modal({      // < Error here
                resizeOnLoad: true
            });
            link.Modal.$Modal.applyTemplateSetup() // < Error here
        }

    }

}
```

When I am using the function I call the function like this:

```
        createModal(link);
```

Am I doing something wrong here? Why is it that I cannot access link inside of the create() ?  Also could I do this with a static function. Would that be easier as I would not have to call the new to make a new instance of Modal ?

Comment: Shouldn't you just add **this** to link? this.link

Comment: @Kao - Thanks you are correct. As far as the second part of my question. Is there any advantage in making this a static class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add `this` to the call, since you need to access the class scope.

---

As far as choosing wether or not to use `static` comes down to how you use the object. Do you have multiple instances of the object, but only always needs 1 copy of it? If so, use `static`.

This means that all of your modal's will be linked together, and there can always only be one.

[Using static in javascript](http://justjs.org/js-oop/static-methods-in-javascript/)

> a static function ( that is there is only one copy of the function no
>   matter how many objects you create) can be real handy for utility
>   functions.